Solidity mapping array of items to an address
I'm making a game where an address will have an inventory of items assigned to it, and players will collect items as the game progresses. What would be the most efficient way to assign a list of items to an address?
I'm thinking to just assign the items each with an id number (1,2,3,etc.). Then have a mapping of address to item array, and when users collect another item its appended to their item array.
Is storing an address to an array the most efficient or would a nested mapping be better in this case?


If frequent lookups dominate (e.g., checking item ownership): Use nested mapping, like:
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => bool)) public inventory;


If maintaining order and iteration are important: Use mapping to an array or the hybrid approach, like:
mapping(address => uint256[]) public inventory;


For a balance between both: You can use a hybrid approach with a struct, like:
struct Inventory {
    uint256[] itemIds;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) itemExists;
}

mapping(address player => Inventory) inventory;

The hybrid approach is ideal when you need efficient lookups (via mapping) and retrievability (via array).


